# Getting value of Value Types in an class using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I wrote the following snippet to illustrate a scenario I faced and can't come up with the answer to the observed behavior:

```
public class X
{

    public string XS { get; set; }
    public int XN { get; set; }
    public MyEnum Enum { get; set; }
}

void testValueTypesReflectionComparison()
{
    var x1 = new X { XN = 1, XS = "argh", Enum = MyEnum.Component };
    var x2 = new X { XN = 1, XS = "argh", Enum = MyEnum.Component };

    var xTypeProperties = x1.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach(var property in xTypeProperties)
    {
        var x1PropertyValue = property.GetValue(x1, null);
        var x2PropertyValue = property.GetValue(x2, null);

        if (x1PropertyValue != x2PropertyValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"different values on property: [{property.Name}]: x1: [{x1PropertyValue}] x2: [{x2PropertyValue}]");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

I could not spot anything in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-7.0) that mention particularities in getting value types.
Why are reflected properties XN and Enum values different in x1 and x2 ?

Comment: Is the answer because value types will be unboxed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `!=` operator is ... non-trivial. Short version: use `object.Equals(x1PropertyValue , x2PropertyValue)`.

By default, `==` and `!=` on an `object` use *reference equality* comparisons. When you use reflection, you get `object` instances, and if the underlying value is a value-type, that means "boxing" is in play, which means each box is a *separate reference*. Two separate boxes of the same value-type value: are not equal under reference equality rules.

This behavior can be *overloaded* by adding operators for specific types, but that requires *knowing the type* (or using the new generic operators feature, which is similar to knowing the type).

To use a more flexible (but also more indirect) approach you can use polymorphism on the `Equals` method, which is what `object.Equals(a,b)` does, with the advantage that `object.Equals(a,b)` doesn't blow up if `a` is `null`, but `a.Equals(b)` does.

Comment: Thanks for help. In the case for the ints, for example, they are unboxed and... when compared using != (this time on Int type) I would not expect that to work ?

Comment: @Veverke I've added a line clarifying that for value-types, you're dealing with boxing; ints are value types

Comment: @Veverke "they are unboxed" you have not unboxed anything; these values are very much: boxed; if you had unboxed them, `==` and `!=` would work, because now they can use the overloaded operators on the specific types

Comment: You mean: value types are boxed because operators != or = requires reference types and thus implicitly "converts" them to their reference representations ("boxed" objects). And as you say, different references, regardless of what the references point to being the same or not, will always **differ**. So nothing is unboxed, indeed (as I wrongly assumed, in the beginning)

Comment: @Veverke no, this has nothing to do with the `!=`/`==` operators requiring reference types; value types are boxed here because `PropertyInfo.GetValue(...)` *returns `object`*; that is the entirety of it; they are boxed *before you see them*; if the types were not boxed (i.e. their specific value-type type was known): then `!=`/`==` would use the most appropriate operator available, which in the case of integers and enums: would act as a *value* equality test

Comment: Thanks for nailing it all down, Marc!